# Are there any other squares $n^2$ for which $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $x$.

Denote the deficiency of $x$ by
$$D(x)=2x-\sigma(x).$$

I am interested in solutions to the equation
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2).$$

**Case 1: $n$ is even.**

In this case, it is known that $n=2^r$ are solutions for $r \geq 1$.

Indeed, we have
$$\gcd(2^{2r}, \sigma(2^{2r})) = 1 = 2(2^{2r}) - \sigma(2^{2r})$$
where the second equation follows from the fact that powers of two are almost perfect.

**Case 2: $n$ is odd.**

*Added September 5, 2018* Note that $n^2 = 1$ is a trivial (odd) solution, as $1$ satisfies
$$\gcd(1, \sigma(1)) = 1 = 2(1) - \sigma(1).$$

In this case, the only known solution (with $n>1$) is
$$n^2 = \bigg({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13}\bigg)^2 = 9018009.$$

Indeed, we obtain
$$\gcd(9018009,\sigma(9018009)) = 819 = 2(9018009) - \sigma(9018009).$$

Here is my question:

> Are there any other solutions?

**My Attempt**

Looking at the OEIS page for [deficient-perfect numbers](http://oeis.org/A271816), it appears that no other solutions are known.  Otherwise, if there existed another odd solution, then we will be able to produce an odd perfect or a spoof odd perfect number whose special prime/quasi-Euler prime has exponent $1$.

Can anybody confirm if my impressions are correct?

*Reference*

[Conditions equivalent to the Descartes–Frenicle–Sorli Conjecture on odd perfect numbers](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf), Notes on Number Theory and Discrete Mathematics, Volume 23, 2017, Number 2, Pages 12—20

Comment: No futher solutions upto $n=10^7$